# How I can split AS code and MXML in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

In Silverlight I can write XAML definition and script logic in different files and it is very convinient are there any way to do same stuff in Flex?

Comment: that was quick...within 5 minutes the two possible ways of doing it were posted. SO still amazes me sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the code behind technique: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/building_components_using_code_behind/

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean the `Script` tag?  It's just:

```
 <mx:Script source="myactions.as" />
```

Comment: This way has the advantage of not requiring you to re-declare all your  MXML components inside the AS file

Answer (score 1):

Besides the techniques described by the other posters here there are more advanced that are not about in which file the code is stored, but how to organize the collaborators and logic of your views. The [Presentation Model pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html) works very well in Flex, but there are also others. I recommend reading [Paul Willams introduction to presentation patterns](http://weblogs.macromedia.com/paulw/archives/2007/09/presentation_pa.html).